# Convert a list or a raw set to a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-1.4

In my django views, I have the following code in my CBV:

```
def get_filtered_queryset(self, queryset):
    filtered_queryset = # some code here
    document_queryset = # some code here
    return set(list(filtered_queryset) + list(document_queryset))
```

How can I change the above function to return a Queryset instead?

Comment: If you are talking about combining two querysets for two different models, you simply cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast `list` or `set` objects into a `QuerySet`.

Depending on the query you are looking at using, you can [construct some pretty complex queries using `Q` Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

For example:

```
from django.db.models import Q
def get_filtered_queryset(self, queryset):
    filtered_queryset = Q(question__startswith='What')
    document_queryset = Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 2)
    return Document.objects.get(filtered_queryset | document_queryset )
```